# PushNotificationType.TileFlyout addition in UWP. What is it?

Tags: push-notification, win-universal-app, uwp, wns

I am building a sample app to test the new push notification features in UWP. I have come accross the new addition in the [`PushNotificationType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.pushnotifications.pushnotificationtype.aspx) enum.
Namely `PushNotificationType.TileFlyout`
Does it suggest that there is a fifth kind of push notification in UWP or is it something else?

I can't find any documentation on it and because of that I can't try it myself since there is no xml schema to base a notification payload on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Namely PushNotificationType.TileFlyout Does it suggest that there is a
>   fifth kind of push notification in UWP or is it something else

Actually, there was a tile called [Flyout Tile](http://www.nokiapoweruser.com/windows-10-interactive-tiles-advanced-notification-center-flyout-tiles-in-works-for-later-versions/)(from Windows 10 Build 9901), it is somewhat similar to old “Zune Mixview”, but it has become **obsolete**.

The PushNotificationType.TileFlyout was to detect it, under Windows.UI.Notifications namespace, see this Bing.com **[Cached page](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=TileFlyoutNotification&d=5006000607334559&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=U4E8SNznTXPkd3ry_zUbmRJb3v_rqW6L)**

> Used to send or clear a tile flyout (mix view) notification. This class also provides methods to start and stop periodic tile flyout notifications.

The APIs related to this Push Notification type have been removed now.

Comment: I had no idea that existed... You solved my question :)